# Android and Ruby On Rails SSL issues( SSL handshake aborted, No peer certificate)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having weird and inconsistent ssl issues while communicating via https between my Android app and RoR web application.

It only happens once every ten times or so.

These are the errors I get in Android:

Android 5.1/One Plus One:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

Android 6.0/Nexus 5

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xa8d3a540: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
```

SSLLabs test gives me the following warning:

```
Chain issues Contains anchor
```